# R - Trouble filtering due to unequally-sized data frames

Tags: r

The following code is an attempt first filter the movies2 data set for Genre and Studio and then create a filtered data frame.

[image]

However, the last line does not seem to work as I am returned the error:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks! Also, if you are vonfused by the question, I will respond promptly.

Comment: Don't include screen shots. use text instead.

Comment: I think the `rbind.data.frame` function might be useful here.

Comment: provide a reproducible example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is creating two different data frames that you could rbind together, but that would not get the result you likely are wanting. It would lead to and "or" for your filters, not an "and".
Using a slightly different approach, but getting the desired result.

```
genre.filter <- c("action", "adventure", "animation", "comedy", "drama")
studio.filter <- c("Buena Vista Studios", "Fox", "Paramount Picture", 
                   "Sony", "Universal", "WB")
movies2 <- subset(movies2, Genre %in% genre.filter & Studio %in% studio.filter)
```